# Flutter: Windows: Error connecting to the service protocol

Tags: flutter

I have no issue running the same app (on the same system) on Web & Android.

Compiling for Windows (in debug mode) give this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
main.dart:1
D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\github\stl\src\mutex.cpp(61): mutex destroyed while busy
Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:56370/nHLYltAvYFs=/
Exited (sigterm)
```

I think the exe launches, but crashes.

Building the exe in release mode gives no build error - but the exe does not run (just a flash on the screen) and the app closes.

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3393], locale en-IN)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 17.7.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.79.2)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.64.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```